# How does the fly-by-wire on the new F/A-18 Super Hornet work and what is it maintaining?

Tags: flight-controls, avionics, fly-by-wire, fa-18

I am trying to replicate the [fly-by-wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fly-by-wire) (FBW) system of the [Super Hornet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_F/A-18E/F_Super_Hornet) for a game called [SimplePlanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SimplePlanes). I was wondering if it is maintaining a certain $g$ number, turn rate, angle of attack, or a mix of everything. And, does anyone an equation that can replicate this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question for the [aviation.se].

Comment: In your simulation, does the pilot have any input?

Comment: @MichaelHall SimplePlane is a game in which you fly a simplistic aircraft. So yes, you do have normal pilot controls, such as stick inputs, throttle, flaps etc.

Comment: My point is that complex FWB computer wizardry needed to keep a marginally stable aircraft controllable isn't needed for simulation.  Just make it do what the (simulator) pilot commands it to do.

Comment: @MichaelHall I think you are right that you don't need the complexity, but the question is not asking for that. The question is what is the FBW trying to maintain? The pilot is commanding the setpoint, and the FBW is trying to match the aircraft state (or state derivative)  to the setpoint. So what is the pilot's stick input commanding:  is it g, pitch, pitch rate, turn rate, roll,  roll-rate etc. To mimic this in a simple simulation you don't need the complex FBW wizardry, but you still need to know what the FBW is striving to achieve.

Comment: @DeltaLima, and the point I was trying to get to in my question is that manual mode isn’t trying to “maintain” anything. It responds to continuously varying stick inputs from the pilot and causes the airplane to maneuver just as a stable, non-computer controlled airplane would. Unless the question is about autopilot, it doesn’t make sense as written.

Comment: @MichaelHall Surely the FBW is trying to maintain something in manual mode. Why else would you have FBW? How does the FBW respond to stick inputs? If I put the stick neutral, what does it try to do? Keep the elevator neutral, maintain 1 G? maintain constant pitch? constant pitch rate? What if I pull a little bit: proportionally move the elevator, maintain a constant G > 1, maintain constant pitch >0, constant pitch rate >0. The relation between the stick input and what  control surfaces are doing is in the hands of the FBW, even if you are flying manually. The FBW control mode/law  is key here

Comment: @DeltaLima, there is a time component to this; when you are maneuvering aggressively nothing is constant for long…. Anyway, in a simulator game there is no need to model real world instability, then model the correction.  Just make the control inputs cause it to fly like any other normal plane.  This is an “XY” question.

Comment: @MichaelHall I think you have a wrong concept about a simulator plane and computer-controlled aircraft. Controlling an airframe via a computer does not "magically" eliminate any dynamic the underlying airframe has. On the other hand if your simulation is setup to "just make it do what the pilot commands it to do" feels very very wrong to the pilot. There is a reason why in real aircraft simulators you go through all the trouble of replicating the FBW control in conjuncture with the aircraft.

Comment: @DeltaLima You are right, it depends on the mode. Pretty much all aircrafts equipped with FBW (except for these with an unstable airframe) have a least a direct mode in which the pilot directly commands the deflections of the control surfaces. The next higher mode up is most of the times one which I describe in my answer. If tuned correctly, such a mode is employed throughout the envelop of the aircraft. The next higher mode up are autopilot functionalities... So to answer your question, in most cases it is rate feedback, or nz feedback or a mixture.

Comment: @U_flow, if the OP were creating a “real aircraft simulator” I would agree with you, but it isn’t for training Naval Aviators. It is for a simple game. Gamers aren't going to notice or care whether the underlying code replicates the FBW computer, hydraulics, or pushrods and cables, they just want something that looks and flies like a Hornet. FYI, years ago I purchased an MS Flightsim add-on that included the A-4 Skyhawk that has a 720 deg/sec max roll rate. It rolled like a 747 in prestall buffet. That felt very wrong to me, but your average gamer might not even pick up on something like that.

Comment: @MichaelHall You have a valid counterpoint, but still, there is a difference between no dynamics at all and something designed to handle nicely. You would be suprised of how good handling qualities contribute to a nice "playability" of simulators.

Answer (score 3):

The F/A-18 relies heavily on computerized control to achieve a number of objectives.
These are (without claiming completeness):

1. Good handling qualities
2. Spin resistance
3. Acceptable High Angle-of-Attack flight and maneuvering characteristics
4. Avoidance of Adverse yaw
5. Avoidance of Proverse yaw
6. ...

How these objective are achieved is described in a [pretty detailed paper](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADP002709.pdf) about the F/A-18 Flight control system available online.

Some key (and pretty standard) concepts are the following:

#### Longitudinal (Pitch) Control

A very standard way to treat the pitch control is to use vertical acceleration feedback ($n_z$) for high-speed and pitch rate $q$ feedback for low-speeds. This is done as pilots judge how much their aircraft pitches at low speed by how much the horizont moves, and at high speed by how much acceleration they feel (remember at higher velocities you feel much more acceleration then you see the horizont move...)
The formula would be
$$ u_x = K_\text{p} e(t) + K_\text{i} \int_0^t e(\tau)$$
whereby $e(t)=d_x - n_z$ ($d_x$ is the pilot input) for high speed and $e(t) = d_x - q$ for low speed. In the intermediate speed range you have a blending of both of these errors. The exact gains for $K_p$ and $K_i$ are also speed dependent and certainly not publicized. They also include special considerations for high AoA which was important at that time, however for a game called *simple* planes, that perhaps makes no difference...

#### Lateral (yaw) control

For lateral control, normally you aim at $\beta=0$ whereby the pedals control how much $\beta$ you build up. Again that is goverened over PI-controllers whereby the gains are scheduled on basis of the velocity. Again the paper describes special spin recovery schemes and anti-adverse-yaw implementations. You will have to decide yourself if you want to implement something like this

#### Roll control

Here, I would simply govern the roll rate $p$, again with a speed-scheduled PI controller

It is worth mentioning that the implementation of a realistic controller relies heavily on a realistic flight model. Therefore if your flight model is simplistic, then your FCS implementation can also be simplistic, but do not expect a high level of fidelity of the overall system. However a realistic FC can be a lot of work to tune, implement and test, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

> ...if it is maintaining a certain g number, turn rate, angle of attack, or a mix of everything...

A mix of everything. The computers adjust the active flight controls for:

- Providing artificial stability of the airframe. An aircraft is most manoeuvrable if it wants to change direction by itself already, which would require constant small inputs from the pilot in order to maintain flight direction. Not a good situation for human handling, the computer has no problems with it though and can artificially create the stable feel for the human.

  [image]
- Limiting the forces on the structure to the maximum design limits. Above image is a still from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRz01UB_DsA), depicting the limiting manoeuvres of an F-16. Active fly-by-wire limits the maximum g-load on the airframe, without having to limit the all-moving-tail area or its maximum deflection angle.

> And, does anyone an equation that can replicate this?

A single equation I don't have unfortunately. There would be at least 6 required for each degree-of-freedom of the aeroplane, each one with quite a few coupled inputs. And the constants in the equations vary from aeroplane to aeroplane and I don't reckon that are published anywhere.